# transfer windows + data from laptop to desktop

Tags: laptop, file-transfer, data-transfer, desktop-computer

I have an old laptop where all my applications (windows, office, itunes, and other apps) and all my data (music, home made video, pictures, documents).

i want to transfer this laptop windows and data to my new desktop (i bought from my friend).

so basially, when i boot the new desktop i want to see the SAME thing as my laptop (windows, user account, pictures, documents, software etc...)

is there a way to do this without reinstalling all the application including windows and putting my data back?

(and yes i will get rid of the windows laptop since its my version - i wont reuse my laptop anymore)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unplug the hard drive from the new desktop and plug it to the laptop using something like:

http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16812196455

Then, download this tool:

http://www.macrium.com/reflectfree.aspx

(there's plenty tools there, this is just an example)

Once the tool is installed, you can **clone** the laptop disk to desktop new disk. Might take sometimes to close. Also, if the laptop disk is bigger than the new drive this won't work. Make sure you have enough space on the desktop disk. If the target disk will have the same configuration of the laptop disk so if you get a 1TB as the desktop disk and the laptop disk is 120GB then you will end-up with 120GB on the desktop disk, you can use some tools to create another partition or resize the disk once its back to the new desktop.

Now, once the disk is cloned, plug it back to the desktop and boot. You will get some errors on the start-up because windows does not recognise any drivers. You will have to re-install all drivers for the new desktop. After few reboots and all driver installed, everything should boot up nicely.

NOTE: this solution is not 100% guarantee, make some backup just in case you have to fresh install windows on the desktop.

Comment: @PereNoel Glad it worked for you, but sometimes those driver errors can be fatal or a pain to fix. Make sure all the ports and everything work on the new machine, make sure it can read the optical drive, test everything. Additionally, beware of your licensing agreement because the key you used is tied (mostly) to the motherboard it was initially installed upon, so Windows _might_ deactivate.

Comment: I had to do the same thing a month ago with http://www.easeus.com/disk-copy/ and it works perfectly, the other computer now is a linux server so no license problem

Answer (score 2):

Most applications have to be re-installed, no way to just transfer them, that being said some application specific data can be transferred after the application is installed on the new PC, you would need to contact the software author or distributor for specific instructions on what data can be moved and how to do it.

Pictures, docs and other files can simply be copied to the new hard drive.

Comment: Despite the other answer is marked as correct and "worked" for the OP (which is awesome), I wanted to put my support into this answer for future visitors.

Comment: There will be issues with using the accepted answer, time will tell.